# ejabberd server domain field

Tags: ejabberd

I tried installing ejabberd on my linux 12.04 machine but I am a bit confused as to what goes into the ejabberd server domain field. I put in localhost but when I start, it opens an error page. I installed using a binary file I downloaded from the process one website. Anybody knows what exactly should go into that field? Thank You.

Comment: that's the XMPP domain for your server.  Usually you want it to be the same than the name of your server in your network,  you can check yours with 

    $hostname

or

    $hostname --fqdn


If you use "localhost" only clients from within the same machine will be able to connect (unless you specifically change the IP settings on your clients on all connecting machines). 

But anyway, this is unlikely to be the cause of any error when starting ejabberd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the domain name as the name that will serve you. For example, if you create a xmpp server for domain users inside your company example.com, the domain is example.com, since accounts with which users will be connected user1@example.com, user2 @ example . com, etc. ..

A single server can serve different domains ejabberd.

As discussed ppolv, usually coincides with the name of your domain in your network, you can configure as well, for example, the DNS server SRV records required for the XMPP protocol.